# Windows Forms DataGridView DataSource

Tags: winforms, list, datagridview, datasource

How do i get a datagridview in a windows forms application to refresh when a assign it to a new list or collection?
My code consists of initializing a list and assign it to the datagridview datasource which works great, and upon clicking a button to search, i'm filtering the list using linq and re-assign it to the datasource, however nothing changes, the datagridview remains showing the initial result.

Comment: Why do you want to re-bind the source with a new list ? You could create a `DataView` object from the datasource instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `List`. Use a `BindingList`.Then the datagridview will automatically update itself when the list is updated. You just have to call .Refresh() on your datagridview.